# Calculate the value of complex polynomial

Tags: java

I am trying to use java to calculate a complexed polynomial function, this is my code

```
public Complex evaluate(Complex z) {
        Complex t=coeff[coeff.length-1].multiply(z);
        int i;
        for(i=coeff.length;i>0;i--){
            t=z.multiply(coeff[i-1].add(t));
        }
        return t;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter real of z: ");
        System.out.println("enter imag of z: ");
        Double m=input.nextDouble();
        Double n=input.nextDouble();
        Complex z=new Complex(m,n);
        Complex[] a=new Complex[] {new Complex(1,1),new Complex(2,2),new Complex(2,3)};
        Complex[] b=new Complex[] {new Complex(0,0),new Complex(1,0)};
        Polynomial A=new Polynomial(a);
        Polynomial B=new Polynomial(b);
        System.out.println("A(z)= "+A.evaluate(z));
        System.out.println("B(z)= "+B.evaluate(z));
    }
}
```

The other part of code works good, but when I test this part(to calculate something like f(z)), I got wrong answer in the end. The method I used in evaluate method is P(z)=a0+a1*z+a2*z^2+a3*z^3=a0+z(a1+z(a2+z*a3)).

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your `evaluate` method the initial value for variable `i` in the loop is wrong. For example, if you have an array of 4 coefficients, like in your example, you first calculate `t = z * a3`. Then you enter the loop and on the first step need to calculate expression `z*(a2 + t)`, but because you start with `i = coeff.length` you actually calculate `z*(a3 + t)`. You should start with `i = coeff.length - 1`. Also, the final value for `i` is wrong, because you'll finish with the expression `z*(a0 + t)`, while you need just simple `a0 + t`. So, check the boundaries of your loop carefully.

```java
Complex t = coeff[coeff.length - 1];
for (int i = coeff.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
   t = z.multiply(t).add(coeff[i]);
}
return t;
```

Comment: This can be simpler and clearer. If you start with `t = new Complex(0, 0);` instead of your initial value, the loop can run from `(int i = coeff.length-1; i >=0 0; i--)`.